# 401 Error When Making Basic Authenticated API Calls to X2CRM

Tags: apache, rest, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

We are encountering a 401 error when making basic authenticated API calls to the X2CRM endpoints (index.php/api2/Contacts). Unauthenticated API calls to other X2CRM VoIP endpoints are successful without issue, and basic authentication works on a test page in the same directory using the same PHP-FPM pool. API calls previously working successfully.

The problem is that API calls to index.php/api2/Contacts or similar endpoints in the X2CRM system are returning a 401 error with "missing user credentials." Basic authentication is working correctly on a test page in the same directory and using the same PHP-FPM pool, and unauthenticated API calls to other X2CRM voip endpoints index.php/api/voip/data/(phone number) are successful without issue. The credentials for the API calls are confirmed to be present in the database

We tried making basic authenticated API calls to the X2CRM endpoints (index.php/api2/Contacts, etc.) using Postman and cURL. We expected the API calls to be successful and return the expected data. However, we encountered a 401 error and the response stated "Missing user credentials". We confirmed that the credentials being used are valid and present in the database. We also tested a basic authentication on a test page in the same directory and it was successful, allowing entry into the directory. We need help resolving the issue with the basic authenticated API calls.

Answer (score 0):

The response that you have shared

> Missing user credentials

means that the credentials that you are trying to send are not being sent with the request.

If those credentials were being sent correctly, then, the error would have been:

> Invalid user credentials

or, something else in the response.

Furthermore, the index.php/api is different from index.php/api`2` so you will need to verify it in the `api2` controller. You can send a request to the following Endpoint to verify if your credentials work with the builtin APIs:

> https://<YOUR_CRM_DOMAIN>/index.php/api2/appInfo.json

Moreover, the [documentation](http://wiki.x2crm.com/wiki/REST_API_Reference#Access_Credentials) clearly indicates that 401 error is related to `Authorization`, so you will need to fix that first.